# Taking the average of of columns for similar rows

Tags: pandas

[image]

What I am trying to do if I have rows with the same prefix,fromMp, toMp
then I take the average of each TPCSpeed 1

for example I have

```
              CF 116 117   54.8    56 50 50 50 50 50 
              CF 116 117   54.8    56 50 50 50 50 50 
              CF 116 117   54.8    56 50 50 50 50 50
```

so If the rows share the same from mp to mp prefix and suffix then I want to take the average TPC 1 of all the rows that share this for example for 116 117 I have TPC 1 (54.8+54.8+54.8)/(3)
I want to take the average of the tpc 1 column for all the rows which share the same info. If the rows do not share the same info I just want the tpc 1. Not sure how to do this maybe duplicates.

I am not sure how to to this in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


result=pd.read_csv("result.csv")
a1=result.columns.get_loc("TPCSpeed1")
a2=result.columns.get_loc("TPCSpeed2")
a3=result.columns.get_loc("TPCSpeed3")
a4=result.columns.get_loc("TPCSpeed4")
a5=result.columns.get_loc("TPCSpeed5")
a6=result.columns.get_loc("TPCSpeed6")
a7=result.columns.get_loc("TPCSpeed7")

pre=result.columns.get_loc("Prefix")
suf=result.columns.get_loc("Suffix")
FromMp=result.columns.get_loc("FromMP")
ToMp=result.columns.get_loc("ToMP")



w1=[]
w2=[]
w3=[]
w4=[]
w5=[]
w6=[]
w7=[]



prefix=[]
suffix=[]
begin=[]
end=[]


for index,row in result.iterrows():
    print(index)
    c1=row[pre]
    c2=row[suf]
    c3=row[FromMp]
    c4=row[ToMp]
    prefix.append(c1)
    suffix.append(c2)
    begin.append(c3)
    end.append(c4)
    
    
    b1=row[a1]
    w1.append(b1)
    b2=row[a2]
    w2.append(b2)
    b3=row[a3]
    w3.append(b3)
    b4=row[a4]
    w4.append(b4)
    b5=row[a5]
    w5.append(b5)
    b6=row[a6]
    w6.append(b6)
    b7=row[a7]
    w7.append(b7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use for `groupby().agg()`.

At it's simplest, you can try:

```
result.groupbby(['Prefix', 'FromMP', 'ToMP', 'Suffix').agg(np.mean)
```

This will collapse all rows that have the same values in all four named columns, and then replace them with a single row with the mean values in each of the other columns. You can use `reset_index()` to get back to the original dataframe.

The `agg` (aka `aggregate`) function is fairly flexible. You can treat columns differently. It doesn't have to be the average for everything.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html